# Google fonts isn't working on my website

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I've tried adding an important tag in the CSS, I've checked the dev console for any errors, and nothing is showing up. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's the effected code:

```css
.links-text {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif, !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oth_style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oth_responsive.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Over The Horizion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="col-12">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li class="navli"><a class="links-text" href="oth_quote.html.">Get A Quote</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navli"><a class="links-text" href="oth_portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navli"><a class="links-text" href="oth_services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I have no idea why it isn't working. I've got it loading up right away in the HTML.

Comment: BTW, check out Material Design Lite and Bootstrap.  Also, if using multiple fonts use one CSS link declaration and pipe them together , e.g., `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,400,700,800|Cabin" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I looked into boot strap, but I'm not really digging it. I like having complete control over the style of the site. I'm doing these websites for clients, so having it perfect is important to me. Also Cabin was the previous font and I decided it doesn't fit the site well. It's deleted now, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma after `sans-serif` in your css.

You could remove both this and the `!important`. Try to avoid using `!important` in your CSS as it can cause a bunch of specificity headaches in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the !important.  Remove that.  Try adding the below to the top of your CSS:

```
html body {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove , important** everything else is fine

```css
.links-text {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oth_style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oth_responsive.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Over The Horizion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="col-12">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li class="navli"><a class="links-text" href="oth_quote.html.">Get A Quote</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navli"><a class="links-text" href="oth_portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navli"><a class="links-text" href="oth_services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```